# Sort the rows according to the order specified in WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (118, 17, 113, 23, 72);
```

It returns the rows ordered by ID, ascending. Is there a way to get back the rows in the order specified in the `IN` clause?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You should use "ORDER BY [FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)". So, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (118,17,113,23,72) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id,118,17,113,23,72)
```

Comment: How is about the performance? Is it slow when re-specify the same id list?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's pretty slow with a table with 500K records

Comment: @Chris have you got a faster way of doing this? I'd be interested in learning about it

Comment: Basically, I'm managing the pagination and sorting by myself out of MySQL. For example:
1) you can use an array whose keys are the primary keys in the correct order
2) you loop the result from the query binding the values to the correct key.

Answer (score 16):

Try using [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,90063,90067#msg-90067):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (118,17,113,23,72) 
    ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '118,17,113,23,72');
```

Comment: How do `find_in_set` compare to `field`?

Comment: @ShiningRay From manual seems that the `FIELD` is a straightforward method and `FIND_IN_SET` is more powerful and complex one that involves the string parsing and `SET` creation.

Comment: Main answer not working for me. but this answer is working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temp table with two columns (ID, order_num):

```
ID   order_num
118  1
17   2
113  3
23   4
72   5
```

Then join:

```
SELECT * from table
INNER JOIN #temp_table 
ON table.id = #temp_table.id
```

Notice that you can drop the `IN` clause.

Sometimes I actually create a permanent table, because then when the client *inevitably* changes their mind about the ordering, I don't have to touch the code, just the table.

**Edit**

The answer using [ORDER BY FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) (which I didn't know about) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Set based approach: create a table-like structure that contains the id values and sort order, and join:

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM (VALUES
    ROW(118, 1),
    ROW(17,  2),
    ROW(113, 3),
    ROW(23,  4),
    ROW(72,  5)
) AS tvc(id, sort)
JOIN tbl ON tvc.id = tbl.id
ORDER BY tvc.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a number to sort on based on the id values:

```
select *
from table
where id in (118,17,113,23,72)
order by
  case id
    when 118 then 1
    when 17 then 2
    when 133 then 3
    when 23 then 4
    when 72 then 5
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the first thing that pops to mind.
note sql is untested, you might need to check correct syntax

its a bit cumbersome, but might do the trick

```
select * from table where id = 118
union 
select * from table where id = 17
union 
.... and so on
```

Comment: No. Without an order by there is no guarantee of the order.